# R: Copying text values from a cell of a dataframe to another cell of another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, repeat

My sincere apologies for changing the content of the question but I just realized the the problem was not about the loops (I was receiving bad results and I initially assumed that is something wrong about the loops. My sincere apologies about that). So I am now writing the actual problem:

I want to transfer the text value of a cell of a dataframe in another text value of a cell of another dataframe.

For instance:

```
dataframe1:

id text
1  athens
2  greece

dataframe2:
id  wordmatch
1   NA
2   NA
```

I am using the following command:

```
dataframe2$wordmatch[1] <- dataframe1$text[1]
```

But instead of having the value "athens" in dataframe2$wordmatch[1] I have the value "1".

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If I were you, I would describe the actual problem and see if you could try avoiding the loop inside a loop situation in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer:**

This unexpected behavior is caused by the fact that the text column of df1 is probably `factor`, and not `character`, to verify, try `class(df1$text)`. You can solve your issue by either doing

```
df1$text <- as.character(df1$text)
```

or

```
dataframe2$wordmatch[1] <- as.character(dataframe1$text[1])
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Old answer on loops:**

Yes, that should be no problem. A working example would be:

```
df = data.frame(nofdelet=c(2,3,4,2))

my_func <- function(i,j)
{
  print(paste0('i: ', i, ', j: ', j))
}

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  for (j in 1:df$nofdelet[i])
  {
    my_func(i,j)
  }
}
```

which outputs:

```
[1] "i: 1, j: 1"
[1] "i: 1, j: 2"
[1] "i: 2, j: 1"
[1] "i: 2, j: 2"
[1] "i: 2, j: 3"
[1] "i: 3, j: 1"
[1] "i: 3, j: 2"
[1] "i: 3, j: 3"
[1] "i: 3, j: 4"
[1] "i: 4, j: 1"
[1] "i: 4, j: 2"
```

Note that you do not have to initialize the loop-variables `i` and `j`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Florian but in my case it does not work. I will edit the question and add the exact code I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked for my test case.

```
repetition <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- data.frame(repetition)

for(i in 1:length(repetition)){
  for(d in 1:df$repetition[i]){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

You don't need to specify `i` and `d` before using them in the loop.

The output of my example is as expected:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
[1] 5
```

E: I just noticed your code uses `for( i in 1:nrow(Sample)){`. Shouldn't it be `sample` instead? Maybe you should check your code for mistakes in case sensitivity.

Comment: thank you pandayo, but in my case it does not work. I will add the exact code I have used.

Comment: Does your dataframe1 include `stringsAsFactors = F` while creating it? Having to use `paste()` could be a result for saving the strings as factors in your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The function paste() needs to be used

```
dataframe2$wordmatch[1] <- paste(dataframe1$text[1])
```